# Visual Studio 2017 stops working when comparing files multiple times

Tags: visual-studio, diff, visual-studio-2017

Is anyone else having this issue? I'm using Visual Studio 2017 to compare two revisions of a file using the Team Explorer window (Git). Everything works until I do another diff. The program freezes and Window's typical "Visual Studio 2017 has stopped working" error message shows up.

I can 100% reproduce this problem every time, but what seems to fix it is **closing** the previous diff before starting the next one.

Comment: Sounds liek a bug, I suggest you report it here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html

Comment: Or use the "Send a smile/send a frown" feature inside Visual Studio or the Visual Studio Installer to report the issue. When using the trace option, it should automatically provide additional information to the development team.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might have to do with extensions. Actually, after adding another one (ReSharper) the issue disappeared.